# Can I alias a language for org-babel SRC blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I've got a new language I'm working on that I'm documenting in an Org file.  Code samples for this language can be written in `lisp-mode`, but I want to use the new language's name for the `SRC` blocks for when I eventually write an Emacs mode for the language.

How can I alias `#+BEGIN_SRC my-new-lang` to open in `lisp-mode`?

Comment: One option that doesn't exactly answer the question as asked is to simply define the new derived mode in elisp without giving it a new implementation: `(define-derived-mode my-new-lang-mode lisp-mode "NewLang")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather late (you've probably finished writing your language and written an Emacs mode for it), but perhaps still useful:

You can `customize` (or manually edit) the variable `org-src-lang-modes`. Without using `customize`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("my-new-lang" . lisp))
```